# Get attribute value from XML

Tags: delphi, xpath, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Anyone can help me how can I get attribute values from the xml?

My XML looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<root>
 <class classtype="TSampleClass" reference_id="1">
 <class name="FList" classtype="TList&lt;class.TKtgSampleClass;" reference_id="2">
  <dynarray name="FItems" count="2" reference_id="3">
    <class index="0" classtype="TRecord" reference_id="4">
      <member name="FID" type="Integer">1</member>
      <member name="FName" type="string">Name1</member>
      <member name="FComment" type="string">comment1</member>
    </class>
    <class index="1" classtype="TRecord" reference_id="5">
      <member name="FID" type="Integer">0</member>
      <member name="FName" type="string">Name2</member>
      <member name="FComment" type="string">comment2</member>
    </class>
  </dynarray>
  <member name="FCount" type="Integer">2</member>
  <class name="FArrayManager" classtype="TMoveArrayManager&lt;class.TKtgSampleClass;" reference_id="6"/>
 </class>
 <member name="FNextID" type="Integer">2</member>
 </class>
 </root>
```

I tried with this:

```
procedure GetValues;
var
  C: Integer;
  vXMLDOC: IXMLDOMDocument;
  vNodes : IXMLDOMNodeList;
  vNode : IXMLDOMNode;
  s: string;
begin
  vXMLDOC := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  vXMLDOC.load(c_FileName);

  vNodes := vXMLDOC.selectNodes('//dynarray/class');

for C := 0 to vNodes.length -1 do
begin
  showmessage(vNodes.item[C].text);
//    s := vNodes.item[C].attributes.getNamedItem('FName').text;
 end;
end;
```

vNodes.item[C].text gives all the values, but I need the values one by one (FID, FName...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you now say, you want to get the attributes of the `<member>` nodes, one way to do it is like so:

```
procedure TForm1.GetValues;
var
  C, i: Integer;
  vXMLDOC: IXMLDOMDocument;
  vNodes : IXMLDOMNodeList;
  vNode : IXMLDOMNode;
  vAttr : IXMLDomNode;
  s: string;
begin
  vXMLDOC := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  vXMLDOC.loadXML(Memo1.Lines.Text);

  vNodes := vXMLDOC.selectNodes('/root/class/class/dynarray/class/*');  // will find ALL nodes
  //  below the final <class> one

  //  OR  vNodes := vXMLDOC.selectNodes('/root/class/class/dynarray/class/member');  // will
  //  find only the <member> nodes below the final <class> one

  for C := 0 to vNodes.length -1 do
  begin
    vNode := vNodes.item[C];
    Memo2.Lines.Add('NodeText: '+ vNode.text);
    for i := 0 to vNode.attributes.length - 1 do begin
      vAttr := vNode.attributes.item[i];
      s := Format('attr name: %s, attr value: %s', [vAttr.nodeName, vAttr.nodeValue]);
      Memo2.Lines.Add(s);
    end;
    //  instead of the `for i:=` loop, you could do something like this
    //  vAttr := vNode.attributes.getNamedItem('name');
    //  s := Format('attr name: %s, attr value: %s', [vAttr.nodeName, vAttr.nodeValue]);
    //  Memo2.Lines.Add(s);

  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks but I know that. With this I get the <class index="0" classtype="TRecord" reference_id="4"> attributes. What I need is the member attributes below like FID, FName and the FComment.

Comment: Sorry, given what was wrong with/missing from your code, I'm a bit surprised you say "I know that".  Anyway, see update

Comment: Also see embedded comment about how to use `GetNamedItem`.

Comment: Thanks MartynA! One more thing, with this I get the result like this."attr name: name, attr value: FID
attr name: type, attr value: Integer" How can i get the other "value"? Above the XML: FName -> Name1?